# ASP classic - Multiple rows in "if"

Tags: asp-classic

What syntax do I use to have ASP classic perform more than one row as a result of an IF?

(I'm not sure I can use "{}" in asp classic)

For example:

```
    If a > 10 then 

    { 
      Response.Write(" a is bigger than ten ! ")
      Response.Write(" And you've just saved the planet ! ")
    }

    end if
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove { and } .

```
If condition Then

    BLOCK of instructions that gets executed if condition = true

Else

    BLOCK of instructions that gets executed if condition = false

End If
```